# Wifi Android Windows Subsystem

Tags: android, windows, subsystem

Can I turn on WIFI and monitor networks via Android Subsystem in Windows 11? How?

Is it possible to connect to others wifi spots.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but the Windows Subsystem for Android has a setting called **"Advanced networking"** (currently under `Advanced settings` > `Experimental features` in the Windows Subsystem for Android Settings app), which is disabled by default. As far as I understand, this means all access to the local network is disabled.

So before you can do any local network operations, you have to enable this setting.